# Cross sum from a number but cross sum should total to one digit

Tags: excel, vba, math, wolfram-mathematica, helper

I want to get cross sum of numbers rounding to one digit.

For example 789 = 24 but I want to get 6 from the first time.

```
Sub quersumme()

Dim a As Integer
Dim ln As Integer
Dim mystring As Integer


On Error Resume Next
mystring = Cells(1, 1).Value

a = 0
ln = Len(mystring)

For i = 1 To ln
a = a + Mid(mystring, i, 1)


Next i

Cells(1, 2) = a

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? What is your question? Remove `On Error Resume Next` and put a breakpoint (F9) on the first line, then you can step through it (F8) and check your variables as you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to keep calculating the cross sum ("quersumme" ) as long as it is greater equal ten.

My suggestion would be

```
Option Explicit

Sub Quersumme_OneDigit()

    Dim res As Long
    res = Cells(1, 1).Value
    
    Do
        res = Quersumme(res)
    Loop Until res < 10

    Cells(1, 2) = res

End Sub

Function Quersumme(ByVal Zahl As Double) As Double
    Dim i  As Long
    Dim Summe As Double

    For i = 1 To Len(CStr(Zahl))
        Summe = Summe + Mid(CStr(Zahl), i, 1)
    Next
    Quersumme = Summe
End Function
```

Comment: thx man. you saved me a lot of time there